# Endless loop when connected to OpenVPN

Tags: networking, openvpn

I connected my university-vpn via openvpn on Windows, Ubuntu and Manjaro.

Windows worked instantly, no configuration was needed.

When using any Linux-System, connecting to the vpn seems to work but when requesting a website (inside or outside of the network I am in) it looks like I am stuck in an endless loop.

Right now I am on Manjaro.

OpenVpn-File:

```
client
dev tun

proto tcp

connect-timeout 20
remote serverFooBar 1195 #correct server is set here

remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass

# the option 'block-outside-dns' is for windows only
# ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
# block-outside-dns

route-metric 1
push-peer-info

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Here is the Certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
```

The result of traceroute is the following:

```
traceroute link.springer.com
traceroute to link.springer.com (172.23.255.252), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.23.255.252 (172.23.255.252)  43.817 ms  3036.501 ms  3065.505 ms
 2  172.23.255.252 (172.23.255.252)  4035.637 ms  4063.329 ms  4063.283 ms
 3  172.23.255.252 (172.23.255.252)  4063.306 ms  4063.299 ms  4063.293 ms
 4  172.23.255.252 (172.23.255.252)  4063.298 ms  4063.270 ms  4063.275 ms
 5  * * *
...
30  * * *
```

resolv.conf sets the dns server correctly too

```
nameserver 172.25.0.1
nameserver myIPv6Adress
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

I suspected the network card to be incompatible with the OS

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
```

Additional hardware information:

```
cpu:
  AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics

network:
  wlp3s0               Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200
  enp2s0               Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

network interface:
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  wlp3s0               Ethernet network interface
  enp2s0               Ethernet network interface
  docker0              Ethernet network interface

bridge:
                       AMD Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
                       AMD Renoir Device 24: Function 3
                       AMD Renoir Device 24: Function 1
                       AMD Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
                       AMD Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
                       AMD FCH LPC Bridge
                       AMD Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
                       AMD Renoir Device 24: Function 6
                       AMD Renoir Root Complex
                       AMD Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
                       AMD Renoir Device 24: Function 4
                       AMD Renoir Device 24: Function 2
                       AMD Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
                       AMD Renoir Device 24: Function 0
                       AMD Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
                       AMD Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
                       AMD Renoir Device 24: Function 7
                       AMD Renoir Device 24: Function 5
```

As a Linux-Novice I am out of options to debug this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That `traceroute` does not look healthy.  What are the routes (`ip route`) after you connect OpenVPN?

Comment: I found out that the main problem has to lay in the DNS.

When trying `drill link.springer.com @172.25.0.1` it responds with `Error: error sending query: Could not send or receive, because of network error`

my resolv.conf looks ok though
```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 172.25.0.1
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: My guess is that your `network error` is due to bad routing, but that is only a guess as you have not posted your routes.

Comment: you were right. I had a look into my routes and set the routes to the network manually.

set these and commented out my local dns. Now it's all working!

`172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.22.255.0/24 via 172.25.84.49 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
172.23.255.0/24 via 172.25.84.49 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
172.25.0.0/24 via 172.25.84.49 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
172.25.84.49 dev tun0 proto static scope link metric 50 
172.25.204.133 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.204.134 metric 50 `